# Refresh page when button is clicked

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, refresh

I have a time clock button which swaps out time stamping the database. it really serves no purpose cause the button takes you to a payroll API I am using to manage the clockin and out functions. I am leaving the button there just so when users are on their dashboard they can see how long they have been clocked in and to be reminded if they are clocked in or out.

If you click the button it opens in new page. so if you click the button again with your refreshing the page it does not open the link again.

How can I refresh this page on click so I can avoid this problem?

```
<div id="clock">
<? if( is_null($row) ): ?>
    <a href="timeclock/index.php" target="blank"  /><button class="btn" id="clock_in">Clock in</button></a>
<? else: ?>
    <label>Last Clocked in</label>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="last_clocked" value="<?= $row['in']?>"><br>
   <a href="timeclock/index.php" target="blank" /><button class="btn" id="clock_out">Clock Out</button></a>
<? endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to open in a new windwo/tab or are you trying to avoid that behaviour? `target="_blank"` (note the underscore) will cause a link to be opened in a new windwo/tab

Comment: If you leave out the underscore it will open in a new window and name that window "blank", which will cause this window to be used each and every time you open a link that has the target "blank"

Comment: blank without the _ makes it open in a new tab. I just want it to open in a new tab and also refresh the page.

Comment: ahh ok ill change that

Comment: but that will not cause the main tab to be refreshed. you will probably have to use javascript to get both your desired effects

Comment: darn. what if I were to put the button in a form and make the action post to self. Would this cause any problems?

Comment: Good call easy fix with java script. Post the answer and I will accept it.. it was just this to fix onClick="window.location.reload()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you put a button inside a link...
Remove the link and just add an onclick eventhandler to the button that opens the new window and refreshes the old window.

```
    <button class="btn" id="clock_in" onclick="window.open('timeclock/index.php', '_blank';location.reload();">Clock in</button>
```

Or if the other way worked fine for you (as you stated in the comments), to have the link call the new window and the javascript reload the page, then just do that :)